# The meaning of "you can give in, you can give out but you don't give up"

Tags: phrasal-verbs, sentence-meaning, songs

I have taken a look at the definitions of all the three phrasal verbs but still not sure what the following sentence means:

> You can give in, you can give out but you don't give up.

A bit more context:

> Sometimes life is scary, sometimes life just seems very unfair. But
> you just gotta hang in there. I'll tell you what I learned down the
> streets Brooklyn New York. You can give in, you can give out but you
> don't give up.

It is from the end of this video:
https://youtu.be/4oh5fEIpx-E

My guess is that it could means something like:
You can be defeated, you can be exhausted but you don't stop trying.

or something like:
You can be defeated, you can complain but you don't stop trying.

Nevertheless, I am not sure at all and I think I may be totally wrong.

Could you please help me understand this sentence?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed rephrasings are correct.

- "*give in*": to agree or to admit defeat after a time
- "*give out*": to break down, to stop working
- "*give up*": to stop trying

The "*to complain*" meaning of "*give out*" seems to be regional and informal. Unlikely the meaning meant here.

Comment: Thanks for help!